# Doxygen (or other tool) document classes and namespaces similarly if at the same level

Tags: doxygen, python-sphinx

I have a bunch of namespaces (containing free functions) and classes (containing member functions, obviously), each of which has a Doxygen comment at the top level and some Doxygen comments for its members. They're within a top-level namespace (one for the whole project) and secondary namespaces (to break the project into packages). Like this:

- `proj/pkg1/foo.hpp`: `class proj::pkg1::Foo`
- `proj/pkg1/bar.hpp`: `class proj::pkg1::Bar`
- `proj/pkg1/baz.hpp`: `namespace proj::pkg1::Baz`
- `proj/pkg2/one.hpp`: `class proj::pkg2::One`
- `proj/pkg2/two.hpp`: `namespace proj::pkg2::Two`

I don't have any `@file` comments. They'd be totally redundant, because there's already exactly one main comment per component, which is attached to the main class or namespace.

I tried running this through Doxygen, and the result is a mess:

- The namespaces and classes are separated into two different hierarchies, both in the header row and the navigation panel. But I want them all in a single tree, because e.g. `pkg2::One` belongs alongside `pkg2::Two`.
- The main hierarchy of namespaces is buried three levels down the navigation panel (Project name -> namespaces -> namespace list). It's next to "Namespace Members" - who uses that!?
- There's another hierarchy for the files (and directories). This is redundant because these exactly match the hierarchy of namespaces (and classes).
- This is digressing a bit now, but I'd also like to add comments to the package namespaces. These have the same problem of separating classes and namespaces (not such a big deal) but also show up various free functions e.g. `operator<<(proj::pkg2::One`.

Is there any way to clean things up a bit? Maybe with Sphinx and Breathe?

### Example screen shot

Here is what Doxygen produces by default on the above code (it doesn't even mention `Baz` and `Two`!), and what I prefer it to look like:

[image: Example mock screen shot]

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. Can you show where the output is not as you expected / small complete example.

Comment: @albert THe most recent version (1.8.15), but I don't think anything relevant has changed recently (I have had the same problem multiple times over the years). I already fully described some example files, and I have added a screenshot of what the output (which is no surprise for anyone used to Doxygen) and a mock up of the sort of thing I am looking for (apologies for my poor PhotoShop skills!). Don't take the mock up too literally, it doesn't have to look exactly like that. I just want to merge classes and namespaces and get rid of some of the junk.

Comment: For the merging of the namelist entities and class entities, I don't have a direct answer, but mybe the grouping (see `\defgroup` etc) might give some results. Regarding the 'Files' entry see the configuration item `LAYOUT_FILE` and the command `doxygen -l ...`. Regarding the line with 'Main page etc' have a look at the configuration setting `DISABLE_INDEX`.

Comment: @albert Thanks, using groups/modules is a a good idea. But as far as I can tell, it would mean writing a lot of boilerplate Doxygen in every file, or writing a script to generate the boilerplate automatically. I think that would be hard to understand/maintain in the long term.

Comment: Well possibly part of the boilerplate can be accomplished with ALIASES where sat the begin of a group part one would have `\beginGroup`, possibly with arguents, and at the end of a group a `\endGroup`.

Comment: Just a quick note of encouragement to say this question _got_ attention. I investigated to propose a solution, but sadly could not find one. Merging the class and namespace trees together would look better, this would be a good improvement to the doxygen tool (in my opinion).

Comment: @MarcAlff Thanks Marc, that is encouraging! Your effort is much appreciated. I find it odd that there aren't better tools out there for generating documentation. Perhaps if you're really serious about documentation you just write it all out by hand.

Answer (score 1):

This is a particularly horrible hack, but I mention it for the record. You could decide that classes are dealt with best by Doxygen, and relabel all the component namespaces (the third-level ones) to classes. Like this:

```
namespace proj {
namespace pkg1 {

/// @brief The Doxygen comment goes here.
#ifdef DOXYGEN
class
#else
namespace
#endif
Baz {
```

Then set `PREDEFINED = DOXYGEN` in the `Doxyfile`.

Obviously, the drawbacks to the this are that it looks ugly as sin in the source code, and it's confusing that it shows up as a "class" in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To get the ball rolling, here's a possible solution:

Change expectations a bit: instead of hoping for the two level structure to be presented to readers all in one go, put up with part of it presented at a time. Make the user click through a separate page for each namespace in the tree:

- The documentation page for the `proj` namespace shows all the packages it contains (i.e. in the example it shows namespaces `pkg1` and `pkg2`).
- Each package namespace page shows all of the classes and component namespaces in it (in separate lists, which is a little annoying, but at least all the stuff for each package is together).

You can hide the tree view with `GENERATE_TREEVIEW=NO` and hide the header row `DISABLE_INDEX=YES`.

The mainpage can just be a link to the top-level `proj` namespace page (with the usual content of the main page moved to the `proj` detailed description) with code like this:

```
/**
@mainpage
@ref proj "Click here for the proj documentation"
*/
```

A slight variation is to manually list the packages in the main page with code like this and bypass the `proj` namespace page. This would work well for a project that doesn't have an overall top-level namespace, or where you want finer control over the main page.

```
/**
@mainpage

Packages:
- @ref proj::pkg1 @n @copybrief proj::pkg1
- @ref proj::pkg2 @n @copybrief proj::pkg2
*/
```